# Are there any trade-offs to daughter chains?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, proof-of-work-security, daughter-chain

There has been some talk of Monero daughter chains to scale up and make payments faster or nearly(?) instantaneous.

Would these daughter chains be less secure in any way: do they trade less confirmations for faster transactions? Would they be more susceptible to a 51% attack? Or are they simply faster because of their limited size?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, daughter chains are not as secure. They do not have the same mining strength that the normal blockchain has with its PoW system.

Daughter chains can be helpful for rapid/instant transactions, where I have good faith the network will not be hacked for someone to steal my $2.